# jsPlumb fired each time I add new instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jsplumb

I have this jsPlumb app, each time I add a new element initPlumb() is fired again.

But the problem is when I add the second element the first connectable has double endpoints:

[image: Double connection]

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hzmrLdL/14/

```
$('button').on('click', initPlumb);
```

Comment: you are calling `initPlumb` twice in your code. once in the append and the second time after the function declaration

Comment: i know. any idea that can fix my situation?

Comment: maybe remove the extra call?

Comment: but i need to make the new html to be an instance of jsPlumb

Comment: Then abstract the function and make them more general this way you will be able to have finely grained control over flow

Comment: can you give me some tips?